# Find the maximum files containing directory in System

Tags: linux, shell

How do I write a shell script to print the name of the directory in the System that contains maximum number of files (including hidden files)?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Without that the question can be down voted

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by a directory containing "files" - do you mean plain files, or do you include all directory entries, including fifos, devices, and directories?  Including `.` and `..`?

Comment: What does the rest of the question say in your book?

Comment: And counting/following symlinks?  Without clarification, it's hard to give a precise answer.

Comment: I'm new in Stackoverflow and also new in linux. @Anatoly.

Comment: @Toby Yes all, you are right

Comment: @MaAc - can you edit your question to resolve the uncertainties as to what it is you wish to count?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the directory containing most ordinary files, you can do something like the following.

```
$  find / -type f -print0 | xargs -n 1 --null dirname | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

It will output the directory with highest number of ordinary files, starting with the number of files followed by the directory name.

Use of `xargs -n 1` is needed for compatibility with older versions of `dirname`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you :) I've updated my answer to a more appropriate one

Comment: You can't use `dirname` with `xargs` like that because it only takes one argument (checked with gnu coreutils 8.13-3.5): `dirname: extra operand [...]`.

Comment: @MichaelJaros Works perfectly for me (GNU bash, version 4.3.39), the purpose of dirname is to cut off the filename from the path and then count the number of duplicates. `xargs` runs `dirname`on each and every path found by `find`.

Comment: @MichaelJaros I am using coreutils 8.24

Comment: Looks like `dirname` has been changed; I have coreutils 8.21, and that accepts multiple arguments, printing one line for each argument.  If you need compatibility, use `xargs -n 1`, if not, then fewer invocations of `dirname` will be more efficient.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks again, and yes, I agree on the use of `sort -n` and after your comment also the use of `xargs -n 1` for comparability, updating answer with that. However afaik `find` shouldn't output empty lines, so option `-r` really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87241/discussion-between-toby-speight-and-rikard-soderstrom).